# Vuong test has different results on R and Stata

Tags: r, stata

I am running a zero inflated negative binomial model with probit link on R (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/zinbreg.htm) and Stata (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/zinb.htm).

There is a Vuong test to compare whether this specification is better than an ordinary negative binomial model. Where R tells me I am better off using the latter, Stata says a ZINB is the preferable choice. In both instances I assume that the process leading to the excess zeros is the same as for the negative binomial distributed non-zero observations. Coefficients are indeed the same (except that Stata prints one digit more).

In `R` I run (data code is below)

```
require(pscl)

ZINB <- zeroinfl(Two.Year ~ length + numAuth + numAck,
  data=Master,
  dist="negbin", link="probit"
  )

NB <- glm.nb(Two.Year ~ length + numAuth + numAck,
  data=Master
  )
```

Comparing both with `vuong(ZINB, NB)` from the same package yields

```
Vuong Non-Nested Hypothesis Test-Statistic: -10.78337 
(test-statistic is asymptotically distributed N(0,1) under the
 null that the models are indistinguishible)
in this case:
model2 > model1, with p-value < 2.22e-16
```

Hence: NB is better than ZINB.

In Stata I run

```
zinb twoyear numauth length numack, inflate(numauth length numack) probit vuong
```

and receive (iteration fitting suppressed)

```
Zero-inflated negative binomial regression        Number of obs   =        714
                                                  Nonzero obs     =        433
                                                  Zero obs        =        281

Inflation model = probit                          LR chi2(3)      =      74.19
Log likelihood  = -1484.763                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     twoyear |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
twoyear      |
     numauth |   .1463257   .0667629     2.19   0.028     .0154729    .2771785
      length |    .038699    .006077     6.37   0.000     .0267883    .0506097
      numack |   .0333765    .010802     3.09   0.002     .0122049    .0545481
       _cons |  -.4588568   .2068824    -2.22   0.027    -.8643389   -.0533747
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
inflate      |
     numauth |   .2670777   .1141893     2.34   0.019     .0432708    .4908846
      length |   .0147993   .0105611     1.40   0.161    -.0059001    .0354987
      numack |   .0177504   .0150118     1.18   0.237    -.0116722    .0471729
       _cons |  -2.057536   .5499852    -3.74   0.000    -3.135487   -.9795845
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnalpha |   .0871077   .1608448     0.54   0.588    -.2281424    .4023577
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       alpha |   1.091014    .175484                      .7960109    1.495346
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vuong test of zinb vs. standard negative binomial: z =     2.36  Pr>z = 0.0092
```

In the very last line Stata tells me that in this case ZINB is better than NB: Both test statistic and p-value differ. How come?

---

Data (R code)

```
Master <- <-read.table(text="
Two.Year    numAuth length  numAck
0   1   4   6
3   3   28  3
3   1   18  4
0   1   42  4
0   2   17  0
2   1   10  3
1   2   20  0
0   1   28  3
1   1   23  7
0   2   34  3
2   2   24  2
0   2   18  0
0   1   23  7
0   1   35  11
4   2   33  13
0   2   24  4
0   2   21  9
1   4   21  0
1   1   8   6
2   1   18  1
0   3   28  2
0   2   17  2
1   1   30  6
4   2   28  16
1   4   35  1
2   3   19  2
0   1   24  2
1   3   26  6
1   1   17  7
0   3   42  4
0   3   32  8
3   1   33  23
7   2   24  9
0   2   25  6
1   1   7   1
0   1   15  2
2   2   16  2
0   1   23  6
2   3   18  7
0   1   28  5
0   1   12  2
1   1   25  4
0   4   18  1
1   2   32  6
1   1   15  2
2   2   14  4
0   2   24  9
0   3   30  9
0   2   19  9
0   2   14  2
2   2   23  3
0   2   18  0
1   3   13  4
0   1   10  4
0   1   24  8
0   2   22  9
2   3   29  5
2   1   25  5
0   2   17  4
1   2   24  0
0   2   26  0
2   2   33  12
1   4   17  2
1   1   25  8
3   1   36  11
0   1   10  4
9   2   60  22
0   2   18  3
2   3   19  6
2   2   23  7
2   2   26  0
1   1   20  5
4   2   31  4
0   2   21  2
0   1   24  12
1   1   12  1
1   3   26  5
1   4   32  8
2   3   21  1
3   3   26  3
4   2   36  6
3   3   28  2
1   3   27  1
0   2   12  5
0   3   24  4
0   2   35  1
0   2   17  2
3   2   28  3
0   3   29  8
0   2   20  3
3   2   28  0
11  1   30  2
0   3   22  2
21  3   59  24
0   2   15  5
0   2   22  2
5   4   33  0
0   2   21  2
4   2   21  0
0   3   25  9
2   2   31  5
1   2   23  1
2   3   25  0
0   1   13  3
0   1   22  7
0   1   16  3
6   1   18  4
2   2   19  7
3   2   22  10
0   1   12  6
0   1   23  8
1   1   23  9
1   2   32  15
1   3   26  8
1   3   15  2
0   3   16  2
0   4   29  2
2   3   24  3
2   3   32  1
2   1   29  13
1   3   26  0
5   1   23  4
3   2   21  2
4   2   19  4
4   3   19  2
2   1   29  0
0   1   13  6
0   2   28  2
0   3   33  1
0   1   20  2
0   1   30  8
1   2   19  2
17  2   30  7
5   3   39  17
21  3   30  5
1   3   29  24
1   1   31  4
4   3   26  13
4   2   14  16
2   3   31  14
5   3   37  10
15  2   52  13
1   1   6   5
2   1   24  13
17  3   17  3
3   2   29  5
2   1   26  7
3   3   34  9
5   2   39  2
3   1   26  7
1   2   32  12
2   3   26  4
9   3   28  8
1   3   29  1
4   1   24  7
9   1   40  13
1   2   27  21
2   2   27  13
5   3   31  10
10  2   29  15
10  2   41  15
8   1   24  17
2   4   16  5
17  2   26  20
3   2   31  3
2   2   18  1
6   3   32  9
2   1   32  11
4   3   34  8
4   1   16  1
5   1   33  5
0   2   17  11
17  2   48  8
2   1   11  2
5   3   33  18
4   2   25  9
10  2   17  5
1   1   25  8
3   3   41  16
2   1   40  13
4   3   25  2
16  4   32  13
10  1   33  18
5   2   25  3
3   2   20  3
2   3   14  7
3   2   23  4
2   2   28  4
3   2   25  19
0   2   14  6
3   1   28  18
8   3   27  11
1   3   25  17
21  2   33  15
9   2   24  2
1   1   16  14
1   1   38  10
16  2   37  13
16  2   41  1
7   2   24  18
4   2   17  5
4   1   37  32
3   1   37  8
13  2   35  6
15  1   23  11
7   1   47  11
3   1   16  6
12  2   36  6
7   1   24  17
4   2   24  8
14  2   24  9
15  2   24  11
0   3   19  4
0   4   28  9
1   1   5   3
11  1   28  15
5   1   33  5
10  2   21  9
3   3   28  8
2   3   13  2
11  2   41  8
4   2   24  11
3   1   32  11
4   2   31  11
7   2   34  3
11  6   33  6
7   3   33  7
2   2   37  13
7   3   19  9
1   2   14  3
6   2   15  11
11  3   37  12
0   2   20  5
7   4   13  6
17  1   52  14
9   3   47  30
1   2   32  27
30  3   36  19
2   2   12  5
3   1   30  7
4   2   19  11
32  3   45  14
13  1   17  7
16  2   24  4
5   1   32  13
7   3   29  14
5   2   46  2
1   2   21  6
1   3   13  17
11  1   41  16
6   2   33  1
7   1   31  20
0   1   16  13
6   3   26  8
11  2   46  7
8   2   20  5
8   1   44  7
2   2   33  12
1   3   22  5
0   4   14  2
4   1   25  8
5   3   24  11
1   1   21  18
5   1   28  5
2   1   51  19
2   1   16  4
17  2   35  2
4   1   35  1
9   3   48  8
2   1   33  16
0   3   24  7
18  2   33  12
11  1   41  5
5   2   17  3
8   1   19  7
4   3   38  2
23  2   27  10
22  3   46  13
5   3   21  1
5   2   38  10
1   2   20  5
2   2   24  8
0   3   30  9
7   2   44  16
7   1   21  7
0   1   20  10
10  2   33  11
4   2   18  2
11  1   45  17
7   2   32  7
7   2   28  6
5   2   25  10
3   2   57  6
8   1   16  2
7   2   34  4
5   2   22  8
2   2   21  7
4   2   37  15
2   4   36  7
1   1   17  4
0   2   23  9
12  2   48  4
8   3   29  13
0   1   29  7
0   2   27  12
1   1   53  10
3   3   15  5
8   1   40  29
2   2   22  11
10  2   20  7
4   4   27  3
4   1   24  4
2   2   24  5
1   2   19  6
10  3   41  10
57  3   46  9
5   1   20  11
6   2   30  4
0   2   20  5
16  3   35  8
1   2   44  1
2   4   24  8
1   1   20  9
5   3   19  11
5   3   29  15
3   1   21  8
3   3   19  3
8   3   44  0
11  3   34  15
2   2   31  1
11  1   39  11
0   3   24  3
4   2   35  6
2   1   14  6
10  1   30  10
6   2   21  4
9   2   32  3
0   1   34  10
6   2   32  3
7   2   50  11
11  1   35  15
4   1   27  9
1   2   32  27
8   2   54  2
0   3   15  8
2   1   31  13
0   1   31  11
0   4   14  5
0   2   37  15
0   2   51  12
0   2   34  1
0   3   29  12
0   2   22  11
0   2   19  15
0   2   39  13
0   3   25  12
0   1   46  2
0   4   42  10
0   1   38  5
0   3   31  4
0   3   33  1
0   2   24  11
0   1   28  16
0   2   28  13
0   1   29  17
0   1   23  13
0   3   36  21
0   2   30  15
0   2   25  12
0   2   26  17
0   3   19  2
0   2   37  5
0   2   47  12
0   1   21  20
0   3   27  21
0   2   16  7
0   1   35  5
0   2   32  24
0   3   31  6
0   3   36  13
0   2   26  20
0   1   31  13
0   2   46  6
0   2   34  12
0   1   18  13
0   1   29  3
0   3   40  9
0   1   25  3
0   3   45  9
0   2   31  3
0   2   35  4
0   3   29  10
0   2   33  13
0   3   22  4
0   2   26  9
0   2   29  19
0   2   28  12
0   2   30  5
0   4   30  3
0   3   32  14
0   3   45  20
0   2   42  9
0   2   25  4
0   2   20  22
0   3   31  5
0   1   26  13
0   2   32  11
0   1   31  2
0   2   42  17
0   1   37  8
0   3   37  16
0   3   25  10
0   2   33  11
0   2   29  7
0   2   21  16
0   3   30  33
0   1   35  8
0   3   25  6
0   2   54  3
0   2   41  10
0   3   35  1
0   4   26  4
0   2   31  4
0   3   26  11
0   3   34  11
0   2   27  7
0   1   19  14
0   1   38  9
0   2   24  1
0   3   30  20
0   4   43  13
0   2   20  10
0   2   38  1
0   2   41  6
0   1   20  9
0   2   34  2
0   2   24  5
0   2   24  2
0   1   31  19
0   3   49  7
0   1   26  0
0   2   44  6
0   3   36  13
0   3   31  14
0   2   30  20
0   1   27  13
0   2   28  9
0   2   22  20
0   4   36  34
0   3   25  3
0   2   29  17
0   2   40  8
0   2   39  17
0   4   29  8
0   1   27  22
0   1   21  10
0   3   17  5
0   3   28  10
0   1   27  7
0   3   40  7
0   2   21  4
0   1   33  14
0   1   31  14
0   3   37  13
0   2   23  9
0   2   25  1
0   2   30  1
0   2   30  12
0   1   41  8
0   2   26  1
0   2   25  14
0   2   26  3
0   3   36  1
0   4   23  1
0   2   18  0
0   2   34  2
0   1   39  6
0   1   16  15
0   3   34  4
0   4   35  6
0   1   22  10
0   1   35  8
0   2   36  13
0   2   50  8
0   2   28  6
0   1   30  14
0   2   33  26
0   3   28  1
0   1   18  10
0   2   27  4
0   2   27  5
0   2   8   2
0   4   32  16
0   3   40  6
0   4   45  15
0   2   38  3
0   2   29  6
0   1   25  9
12  1   27  5
2   1   33  8
4   3   31  3
1   1   33  4
0   3   20  5
0   2   28  6
2   2   32  12
0   3   30  2
0   3   19  3
1   1   14  19
0   2   28  2
0   3   26  3
0   2   32  13
1   3   21  7
1   4   20  0
2   2   40  8
0   2   35  18
1   1   20  6
6   2   21  3
3   2   33  10
1   1   31  15
1   2   22  5
0   2   24  7
2   2   22  3
3   2   17  6
9   2   30  12
2   4   39  9
0   2   46  8
0   2   26  5
1   2   28  5
6   1   18  3
5   2   19  13
1   3   27  3
1   1   20  10
0   1   27  6
0   4   26  1
0   2   19  4
0   1   26  8
1   1   30  8
0   2   22  2
3   3   42  4
3   1   10  5
3   1   30  12
1   1   25  8
1   2   38  8
2   1   28  13
3   1   18  12
2   2   20  11
2   2   29  0
1   2   18  3
1   1   6   2
0   1   6   3
2   2   24  1
0   1   14  1
1   1   17  5
2   2   20  9
1   4   24  0
1   2   8   10
0   2   18  1
1   1   25  5
2   2   12  7
0   3   18  1
0   1   19  1
8   2   21  2
1   2   23  5
7   2   19  6
1   1   21  5
0   1   16  6
1   1   24  1
0   2   19  3
1   2   14  6
3   2   24  2
6   1   32  21
0   1   16  0
1   2   15  0
1   2   8   8
0   1   14  5
0   2   27  5
2   2   17  2
1   1   19  7
1   2   21  2
0   1   29  7
0   2   18  2
0   2   15  6
2   3   27  3
0   2   57  4
2   3   17  2
1   1   18  8
1   1   17  5
0   1   18  1
1   2   18  4
1   1   12  1
0   2   15  6
1   2   24  4
3   2   14  9
0   1   24  6
3   1   30  9
0   1   19  5
3   1   16  7
5   3   21  1
2   2   17  5
4   1   34  9
1   1   17  7
3   2   30  10
12  1   17  6
2   1   26  6
1   1   18  2
2   2   24  0
0   1   12  2
0   2   3   2
1   1   11  4
1   4   18  13
0   1   25  9
8   2   20  7
0   1   11  7
7   3   26  19
6   1   18  6
6   2   32  5
1   1   31  2
1   2   33  9
4   1   17  6
1   2   34  11
5   1   37  3
0   3   27  10
12  2   25  14
3   1   40  6
6   2   27  9
0   2   31  2
1   1   28  7
2   1   37  11
1   1   19  0
5   2   30  17
4   3   40  6
0   1   27  6
5   3   31  7
0   3   26  10
3   2   32  4
1   3   43  6
3   1   19  3
2   2   37  4
0   3   28  4
6   3   30  11
1   1   30  9
4   3   31  26
1   2   14  1
10  1   35  27
1   1   36  7
5   1   32  8
2   1   28  6
3   1   34  16
3   2   32  5
1   3   11  0
2   2   42  5
0   2   30  7
0   1   32  9
3   3   43  2
7   2   43  6
1   2   21  5
2   1   27  20
1   2   37  7
2   1   37  8
0   1   19  3
0   3   28  5
2   2   33  3
3   1   41  6
13  2   41  9
2   1   38  3
4   1   32  5
2   1   34  8
1   1   27  9
8   1   29  7
4   1   17  6
0   1   20  8
1   2   34  4
1   1   16  11
4   2   33  5
0   2   15  6
1   1   27  4
2   3   15  8
1   1   30  8
3   2   41  20
0   1   25  15
1   3   35  24
4   2   30  21
6   2   30  6
16  2   33  21
2   3   37  3
2   2   30  12
4   1   57  11
0   2   18  16
4   4   20  13
3   1   43  10
3   1   25  15
7   2   31  11
2   1   31  3
5   2   40  11
3   2   28  7
4   2   27  10
0   1   26  6
4   2   24  14
4   2   23  8
0   2   25  11
21  2   33  12
1   3   37  0
3   2   28  7
4   2   27  10
1   2   41  15
2   2   30  16
2   2   28  7
6   1   19  8
4   4   22  19
0   2   38  33
1   1   29  11
1   2   27  2
4   2   24  6
2   1   22  5
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

Comment: I think you can easily compute the Vuong test, once you have estimated two models. See Greene's book for formula. You can also see how it is computed in R using `library (pscl)` and then typing `vuong` and in Stata you can type `viewsource zinb.ado`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above problem occurred with `pcsl` version 1.4.6. I spoke to the author since and in version 1.4.7 he fixed the bug. The actual version in February 2015 is 1.4.8.